# Assigning one column to another column between pandas DataFrames (like vector to vector assignment)

Tags: pandas

I have a super strange problem which I spent the last hour trying to solve, but with no success. It is even more strange since I can't replicate it on a small scale. 
I have a large DataFrame (150,000 entries). I took out a subset of it and did some manipulation. the subset was saved as a different variable, x.

x is smaller than the df, but its index is in the same range as the df. I'm now trying to assign x back to the DataFrame replacing values in the same column:

```
rep_Callers['true_vpID'] = x.true_vpID
```

This inserts all the different values in x to the right place in df, but instead of keeping the df.true_vpID values that are not in x, it is filling them with NaNs. So I tried a different approach:

```
df.ix[x.index,'true_vpID'] = x.true_vpID
```

But instead of filling x values in the right place in df, the df.true_vpID gets filled with the first value of x and only it! I changed the first value of x several times to make sure this is indeed what is happening, and it is.  I tried to replicate it on a small scale but it didn't work:

```
df = DataFrame({'a':ones(5),'b':range(5)})
     a   b 
0    1   0
1    1   1
2    1   2
3    1   3
4    1   4 

z =Series([random() for i in range(5)],index = range(5))
0    0.812561
1    0.862109
2    0.031268
3    0.575634
4    0.760752

df.ix[z.index[[1,3]],'b'] = z[[1,3]]
     a    b
0    1   0.000000    
1    1   0.812561
2    1   2.000000
3    1   0.575634
4    1   4.000000
5    1   5.000000
```

I really tried it all, need some new suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`df.update(updated_df_or_series)`](http://bit.ly/1jB4N1X)

Also using a simple example, you can modify a DataFrame by doing an index query and modifying the resulting object.

```
df_1
   a  b
0  1  0
1  1  1
2  1  2
3  1  3
4  1  4

df_2 = df_1.ix[3:5]
df_2.b = df_2.b + 2
df_2
   a   b
3  1   5
4  1   6   

df_1
   a  b
0  1  0
1  1  1
2  1  2
3  1  5
4  1  6
```